# Strange border when drawing shapes in onDraw (only SGS2)

Tags: android, drawing, samsung-mobile

I'm having some issues when drawing shapes (i.e. with drawRect). Shapes always look ok, but when I run the application in a Samsung Galaxy S2, I see a 1px darker border around the shape.

This only happens in SGS2, not in other phones or tablets, nor in the simulator.

This what I can see when the application run in the SGS2.

Cannot post a picture since I'm new here, but this is a test app which only draws a Rect on the screen: http://www.nvingenieria.com/optonet/apps/testal.apk.

Anyone having this issue? Someone having a SGS2 can help?

Comment: I will try to get back to you when I am home today (8-9 hours, sorry) as I have a SGS2. Can you post your code for drawing the rectangle in the meantime? Also, if you want to post a picture here without the rep you can make an upload to imgur.com and paste the link here.

Comment: I'm really sorry not to answer before, but I thought the answers would be sent to my email.

Comment: I have a test app in www.danielnavarroymas.com/apps/test.apk and in www.danielnavarroymas.com/apps/test.rar (code). I'will provide you with an image in a few minutes... thanks in advance...

Comment: And these are images: www.danielnavarroymas.com/apps/screen.jpg (whole screen) and www.danielnavarroymas.com/apps/detail.jpg (red rectangle detail).